# Understanding Entity group limitations

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to understand how to tackle there two limitations of google datastore

> write throughput limit of about one transaction per second for a
> single entity group.
>
> All the data accessed by a transaction must be contained in at most 25
> entity groups.

suppose I wanted to store users info. Due to the 1st limitation I cant store them in a entity group, as several users may update their info at same time. Now if i try to save all users as root entities the 2nd limitation says i cant use any query on users (like find a user whose age > 10). Now i am wondering how is datastore even usable with such limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the 2nd limitation: you can, of course, query all users for those whose age > 10, only you must not do it inside a transaction.

If consistency is important you can:

1. perform a keys-only query outside a transaction
2. obtain a list of up to 25 keys to operate on (for example by using [Query Cursors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/query-cursors))
3. inside a transaction access (by key) the entities corresponding to the keys in your list - these accesses will be consistent

Answer (score 1):

A query isn't a transaction - the returned results can be spread across any number of entity-groups.